# What is Google Play Services' "location with low power consumption"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

According to [TEKNOLOGYA](https://www.google.com/amp/s/teknologya.com/disable-or-uninstall-google-play-services/amp/), Google Play Services "offers features that allow you to manage access to Google services, the location with low power consumption, the management of privacy settings and the installation and update of all applications from the Play Store."

Could someone help me understand what is "a location with low power consumption" in Google Play services? Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Google Play Services allows you to manage access to ... the location with low power consumption

This is a bit poorly worded since “with low power consumption” seems to modify “access” rather than “location”.

High-accuracy location (in particular GPS) is a surprisingly power-hungry service, so what this is saying is that Google Play Services allows you to manage access to location in a way that reduces power consumption. I suspect they do that by giving apps a lower-accuracy location when running in the background, similar to how they limit CPU and data use, but you’d have to read the developer documentation to be sure.

Comment: Thank you all so very much for your detailed explanations !

Answer (score 0):

Google Play Services adds functionality to Android devices, and gives developers access to useful features.

For example, some apps want to be able to access your location, but using the sensors to get this information can use a lot of power - especially if they need to check your location often. And one feature that Play Services offers is a [more efficient way of getting location data](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/battery).

The English in your link is very strange, by the way - "the location with low power consumption" doesn't really make sense (I know what they mean, but it doesn't read very well).